# Revoking permission to install plugins?

Tags: mariadb

The following query was used as part of a security audit to identify users with access to install/uninstall server plugins at the database level.

```
SELECT user, host FROM mysql.db WHERE db = 'mysql' and (insert_priv='y') or (delete_priv='y') or (insert_priv='y' and delete_priv='y');
```

I need to revoke that permission from the users that are listed.  Is there a specific privilege I revoke to do this? If so, I can't find it.  Or would I simply UPDATE the insert_priv and delete_priv fields directly in the mysql.db table?  I'm not a DBA but the closest thing we have at the moment.

Comment: I'm aware of changing permissions that way, but as I said I don't see anything in that documentation that pertains specifically to plugin installation

Comment: The `WHERE` condition in your query looks weird, specially the combination of `AND` and `OR` one time with brackets, one time without. Is that query correct? What should that query return?

Comment: yes it is correct query from the documents I was given and I agree I thought it looked a bit weird as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are able to install plugins when you have `INSERT` permissions on the `mysql.plugin` table, see [INSTALL PLUGIN](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/install-plugin/):

> To use `INSTALL PLUGIN`, you must have the `INSERT` privilege for the `mysql.plugin` table.

So when you have database wide `INSERT` permissions on the (internal administrative) database `mysql`, then you can install plugins.

The same goes for the `UNINSTALL PLUGIN` statement, see [UNINSTALL PLUGIN](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/uninstall-plugin/)

> To use `UNINSTALL PLUGIN`, you must have the `DELETE` privilege for the `mysql.plugin` table.

Remove the `insert_priv` and `delete_priv` privileges for the `mysql` database, your "normal" MySQL user accounts shouldn't be able to write in this database anyway.

Comment: Thanks for that, it clarifies things.